# How to find if data_change event in excel is fired by local user

Tags: office-js

In excel co-auth environment when user A modifies the cell onDataChange event fires on all users workbook where onDataChange event is subscribed.

I run a custom logic on data_change event.I want to run this logic only when I modify the cell in my workbook.

If data_change event fires as a result of cell change in some other workbook I don't want to skip the custom logic in data_change event.

How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to currently determine local changes from remote coauthor ones. This is true for both Excel and Word.  Word Desktop does support co-auth, but even there, there is no way to tell local from remote changes in VBA.

It would be great if you could describe the scenario that you're trying to achieve, and I'll circle it around within the team.